# How do websites code those "What Character Are You" Facebook links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, hyperlink

Here is an example of what I am referring to: [Facebook Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ2aL.png)

I don't understand how this is coded. Is it simply some code that states if your name begins with the letter "A" then you are this person, "B" then this person, etc... or is it more complex then that. I have seen people whose names both begin with "A" get different results, so could it be just a random result? And how would this all be coded on the website's end, since Facebook just pulls up an image/text preview of the site (which is also another question, how could so many "sites/name" exist for every name possible)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Probably some black magic that can read the user's mind... All jokes aside, how are we supposed to know how those websites implement this?

Comment: Are you trying to build one?  Or are you just speculating?

Answer (score 1):

There is many different ways this could be achieved but if you were speaking generally I would assume they where chosen at random for either an object, array, database etc. An example of this would be the following using a JavaScript array

```
const la = ["Goofy", "Bugs Bunny", "Yosemite Sam", "Porky Pig"]
const generateRandomCharacter = () => { 
    return `Your character is: ${la[Math.floor((Math.random() * la.length} + 0)]}`)
}
alert(generateRandomCharacter) /* would return your random character */
```

running the `generateRandomCharacter` would return your random character.
Again this could be achieved many other ways this is just an example.

For your question about 'how that many sites could exist' well from my very minimal experience with php I create a site that would write a new file each time a user loaded. I speculate that whenever you were to click the button to generate your character it was writing a file with your randomly chosen character and your facebook name as the filename but again my php knowledge is very minimal.

Hope this helped somehow.